# Generate different permutations/combinations in a string

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7

I am given a string (eg "12345678").
I want to generate different combinations using `+`,`-`,`*`,`/`.
Like :

```
'1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8'
'1+2*3-4+5+6-7+8'
'1-2+3+4*5+6-7*8'
'1-2-3-4+5*6+7+8'
'1+2+3+4+5+6*7*8'
'1-2+3-4+5-6+7-8'
```

Any idea how do i generate all different combinations like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is one way to achieve this:

```
from itertools import product

numbers = "123456"
for operators in product('+-*/', repeat=len(numbers)-1):
    ret = numbers[0]
    for op, n in zip(operators, numbers[1:]):
        ret += op+n
    print(ret)
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) creates pairs of elements of two iterators. the rest is just string manipulation (and not in a very good way).

this is a little more compact (and pythonic?) with some more [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools) magic:

```
from itertools import product, zip_longest, chain

numbers = "123456"
operators = '+-*/'
for ops in product(operators, repeat=len(numbers)-1):
    print(''.join(chain(*zip_longest(numbers, ops, fillvalue=''))))
```

[`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product) is well documented. with [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.zip_longest) i create an iterator that will yield the pairs `('1', '+') , ('2', '*'), ... , ('6', '')` (the last item is filled with the `fillvalue`; `ops` is one element shorter than `numbers`). the [`chain(*...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.chain) idiom is a simple way to flatten the tuples to get an iterator over the strings `'1', '+', '2', '*', ..., '6', ''`. then i simply [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) these strings.

if you don't like the `chain(*...)` part, you can replace it with [`chain.from_iterable(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.chain.from_iterable) (this time without the `*` which may be a bit cleaner).

Comment: yes but i need combinations of '+' & '-' & '*' & '/'

Comment: using above method wont give me that   
like
1+2*3-4+5+6-7+8

Comment: thank you..yes that is what i wanted.. however can u explain this code..like what the package "product" does..&& ..what is "zip" command